# Am using PHPMailer to send mails but getting errors

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

Am sending mails using phpmailer but getting errors like SMTP->connect() failed. May I know, what is the issue in my code?

```
<?php
/**
 * This example shows making an SMTP connection with authentication.
*/

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't 
have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS 
encryption, `ssl` also accepted
//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port = 587;
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "xxxx@gmail.com";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "xxx";
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('xxx@gmail.com', 'First Last');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('xxxx@gmail.com', 'John Doe');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images 
to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
//$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

Getting error as

> 2019-03-18 08:57:16 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP f65sm16549874pff.21 - gsmtp
>   2019-03-18 08:57:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
>   2019-03-18 08:57:17 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [106.51.228.74]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250 SMTPUTF8
>   2019-03-18 08:57:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
>   2019-03-18 08:57:17 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
>   SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
>   2019-03-18 08:57:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
>   2019-03-18 08:57:17 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
>   2019-03-18 08:57:17 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 
>   SMTP connect() failed.
>   Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: Have you turned ON less secure app in Google. follow the link to enable it https://myaccount.google.com/security

Comment: This has nothing to do with the "less secure app" setting. The need for that has entirely different symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is failing immediately after `STARTTLS`. This exact problem has been discussed many times before on here and is [described extensively in the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure) linked from the error message.

In short, your CA certificate bundle is outdated; update it.